# How to retrieve iframe top position in IE6 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-6, position

Does anyone know how to retrieve an iframe top position within a page for IE6 using JavaScript?

The following code works for IE7: window.frames(0).screenTop

but the same code in IE6 retrieves the wrong value (far too high).

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a dupe of this question: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dyanamically-reterive-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript">Dyanamically reterive Html element (X,Y) position with JavaScript</a>

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to retrieve an iframe top position within a page for IE6 using JavaScript?

The same way as for any other element, using offsetTop (and adding up offsetTop from any offsetParent ancestors). It doesn't matter that it's an <iframe> element.

```
var el= document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var top= 0;
while (el && el.nodeType==1 && el!==document.documentElement) {
    top+= el.offsetTop;
    el= el.offsetParent;
}
```

> The following code works for IE7: window.frames(0).screenTop

I doubt that works. screenTop is the wrong thing, it's the on-screen co-ordinates not on-page. And in any case it would have to be square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to use `offsetTop`. Of course, you'll have to loop, adding the `offsetParent`'s `offsetTop` until the `offsetParent` is null.

Both [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) and [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/positionedoffset) do this for you.

In fact, here's the code from Prototype:

```
  positionedOffset: function(element) {
    var valueT = 0, valueL = 0;
    do {
      valueT += element.offsetTop  || 0;
      valueL += element.offsetLeft || 0;
      element = element.offsetParent;
      if (element) {
        if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'BODY') break;
        var p = Element.getStyle(element, 'position');
        if (p !== 'static') break;
      }
    } while (element);
    return Element._returnOffset(valueL, valueT);
  }
  //Element.getStyle returns the style or its default if not defined.
  //Element._returnOffset returns the left and top as a single object
```